# Temperature Convertions

Tags: java, temperature

I have to convert a temperature in degrees Celsius to Fahrenheit. However when I print the temperature in Celsius I get the wrong answer ! Please help ! (The formula is c = (5/9) * (f -32). When I type in 1 for degrees farenheit I get c = -0.0. I have no idea what is wrong :s

Here is the code

```
import java.io.*; // import/output class
public class FtoC { // Calculates the temperature in Celcius
    public static void main (String[]args) //The main class
    {
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in); // Gets user input
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr); // manipulates user input
    String input = ""; // Holds the user input
    double f = 0; // Holds the degrees in Fahrenheit
    double c = 0; // Holds the degrees in Celcius
    System.out.println("This program will convert the temperature from degrees Celcius to Fahrenheit.");
    System.out.println("Please enter the temperature in Fahrenheit: ");
    try {
        input = br.readLine(); // Gets the users input
        f = Double.parseDouble(input); // Converts input to a number
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    c = ((f-32) * (5/9));// Calculates the degrees in Celcius
    System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you all so much :) I was so confused haha :p

Answer (score 4):

You are doing integer division, and hence `5 / 9` will give your `0`.

Change it to *floating point division*: -

```
c = ((f-32) * (5.0/9));
```

or, do the *multiplication* first (Remove the brackets from division): -

```
c = (f-32) * 5 / 9;
```

Since, `f` is double. Numerator will be `double` only. I think this way is better.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using double instead of int as this would lead to loss of precision. Instead of using the whole formula, use one calculation at one time

Example: Use appropriate casting
Double this = 5/9

F - Double 32

Answer (score 0):

use this rather:

```
c = (int) ((f-32) * (5.0/9));// Calculates the degrees in Celcius
```

as it involves division and you should not use only ints to get proper division

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
System.out.println((5F / 9F) * (f - 32F));
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless explicitly specified otherwise, Java treats all numbers as integers.  Since integers cannot store fractional parts of numbers, when integer division is performed, the remainder is discarded.  Therefore: `5/9 == 0`

Rohit's solution `c = (f-32) * 5 / 9;` is probably the cleanest (though the lack of explicit types may cause a bit of confusion).