# Any ideas on how to get my Temp converter to work?

Tags: java, eclipse

```
package tempConverter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TempConverter {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int f;
        int c;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter the Temperature that is in Fahrenheit: ");
        f = input.nextInt();
        c = (5 / 9) * (f - 32);
        System.out.print(f);



    }

}
```

Where am I going wrong on this one?

Comment: what doesn´t work? (you might want to print `c`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Temperature Convertions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13946711/temperature-convertions)

Comment: ``System.out.print(c);`` Kevin already said

Comment: I have fixed it to System.out.print(c); and now It only prints 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace type of `c` variable to `double`

This example should working fine

```
package tempConverter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TempConverter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter the Temperature that is in Fahrenheit: ");
        int f = input.nextInt();
        double c = (f - 32) * 5 / 9;
        System.out.format("%.2f%n", c);
    }
}
```

Comment: `$ javac tempConverter/TempConverter.java`
`$ java tempConverter/TempConverter`

Please enter the Temperature that is in Fahrenheit: 55
12.00

Why it shouldn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing 5/9 which will be always zero as your c is integer.
Change c to float, and use
c =5(f-32)/9;

Answer (score 0):

Change the 5/9 to 5.0/9.0, which will force it to do double arithmetic instead of integer arithmetic which will truncate the 5/9 to 0, and chance c to type double.